# Obtener archivos de un input

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp

Tengo una vista en ASP.Net MVC, donde en el formulario deberia tener:

```
    <input type="file> 
    <input type="file multiple="multiple">
```

Uno para subir una imagen de portada, y otro para subir varias imagenes. Lo que no se es como obtenerlas por separado. Trate haciendo que el controlador sea algo asi:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegistrarNoticia(Noticia model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        HttpFileCollectionBase imagenes = Request.Files;
        return RedirectToAction("RegistrarNoticia");
    }
```

Pero me salta un error de "Se excedió la longitud de solicitud máxima." Alguna sugerencia de como podria obtener la imagen de portada(unica) y la imagenes de la noticia (max5) separadas para poder tratarlas de forma diferente? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione, muestro la forma en que lo hice por si a alguien le pasa. En el Web.Config tienen que agregar esta linea:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />    
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="20971520" /> 
  </system.web>
```

De esa forma expanden el limite en kb que permite subir archivos el framework.
La linea en cuestion es la de httpRuntime, que debe estar dentro de system.web